# How to use wildcards in strpos

Tags: php, regex

I have the below script which is working. I am looking for the string '1/72'
I would also like to look for the string '1:72' and '1\72' - how would I go about doing this easily (apart from just using multiple if statements?)

```
$string="test string 1/72 PHP";

if (strpos($string, '1/72') > 0) {
        print "Got match!\n";
    } else {
        print "no match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_match` function.

```
if (preg_match("~1[\\\\:/]72~", $str)) {
```

`[\\\\:/]` character class which matches a backslash or `:` or forward slash.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xL6tD6/1)

Comment: Brilliant! One line of code! I need to master regex! :)

Answer (score 1):

The [fnmatch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) function also provides a simple way to use pattern matching with [shell wildcard expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_50.html)

```
$string="test string 1/72 PHP";

if (fnmatch('*1[/:\\\\]72*', $string)) {
    print "Got match!\n";
} else {
    print "no match\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Though with fnmatch I get a error saying it's been disabled for security reasons. A quick Google says I need to do some editing of the php.in I file.

Comment: In PHP, it's possible to disable any function through the php.ini.... quite why fnmatch() should be disabled I don't know, but it's a nothing other than a standard PHP function